# How to connect Apache Superset to local db

Tags: mysql, apache-superset

I am trying to connect my localdb to Apache SuperSet

[image]

Below is the error:
Password is Blank not sure what's wrong

[image]

Comment: Can you also post the log? Like Patrick said, you should try changing format. But, log will have more detail.

Answer (score 0):

In the URI change `root@` to `root:<password>@`.